# Module get killed at write on sys call table

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I try to write a Kernel module which hooks the system read function. But as soon as I try to write the pointer of my function into the sys call table the module gets killed. Here is my init function:

```
int init_module(void)
{
  // set rw/ro functions
  patch_set_memory_rw = (void *) kallsyms_lookup_name("set_memory_rw");
  patch_set_memory_ro = (void *) kallsyms_lookup_name("set_memory_ro");

  if( patch_set_memory_rw == NULL ||
      patch_set_memory_ro == NULL){
    // something went wrong
    printk(KERN_ALERT "ERROR WITH RW/RO!");
    return 1;
  }
  // Inform that module is staring
  //printk(KERN_INFO "Start Hook Read.");
  syscall_table_pu64 = (void **)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");

  //for debugging
  //printk(KERN_ALERT "syscall addr is %llx", syscall_table_pu64);


  // swap read call with own read function
  orig_read_p = syscall_table_pu64[__NR_read];
  // set memory rw to change it
  patch_set_memory_rw((uint64_t)syscall_table_pu64, 1);
  syscall_table_pu64[__NR_read] = own_read_func;
  return 0;
}
```

The error happens in the line

```
syscall_table_pu64[__NR_read] = own_read_func;
```

Does anyone know what my problem is? I can't figure it out.
The error messages are

```
RIP: init_module+0x76/0xa0 [hook_read] RSP: ffffa4ad46233c70
```

and

```
RIP: 0033:0x7f01920bb839
[ 3476.855557] RSP: 002b:00007fffcc925288 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[ 3476.857431] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000559daa9f6790 RCX: 00007f01920bb839
[ 3476.858902] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000559daa012c2e RDI: 0000000000000003
[ 3476.860550] RBP: 0000559daa012c2e R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007f019238e000
[ 3476.861959] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
[ 3476.863399] R13: 0000559daa9f6760 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[ 3476.864747] Code: 89 05 d7 22 00 00 48 8b 10 48 89 c7 be 01 00 00 00 48 8b 05 d5 22 00 00 48 89 15 b6 22 00 00 e8 71 3f 26 e2 48 8b 05 b2 22 00 00 <48> c7 00 00 f0 59 c0 31 c0 5d c3 48 c7 c7 40 00 5a c0 e8 f3 f1
```

Comment: syscall table are readonly, nd so you cannot change its values or add new entries.

Comment: Yes, but I disable the write protection before. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I finaly figured my problem out. In order to remove the write protection from syscall you can (of course) not use the linux syscall of it :D Took me 3 hours to realize that. Instead use

```
write_cr0 (read_cr0 () & (~ 0x10000));
```

to enable write and

```
write_cr0 (read_cr0 () | 0x10000);
```

to make your memory read only again.

Answer (score -1):

The system call table is read-only. Do not attempt to modify it.

If you want to hook read/write operations, you will need to choose another way of doing so. One mechanism you may want to investigate is the [kprobes](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt) system.